# How to Debug/troubleshoot outlook addin for mobile

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-mobile-addin

I have recently added MobileFormFactor in manifest.xml. If we load a custom addin in outlook client, question is how can we debug this addin when using android mobile outlook client in windows

I tried fiddler, I want to see office js calls happening when using addin in outlook mobile

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism for debugging add-ins on Android. You can treat Office web add-ins like a regular web applications and use any remote JavaScript debugging techniques available for Android. For example, take a look at [RemoteJS](https://remotejs.com/), [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com/) or [JS Console](https://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging).

Also see [Node.js debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) if you are building your add-in on top of NodeJS.